# Is there a way to have vertical stripes on all timelines?

Tags: animation, theme

I find it difficult to visualize and calculate a 1 second of time with a solid grid slab. I thought maybe if there was a background pattern that slices a second or a half second into vertical bands would make it easier to time animations.

Image is a mock up of what I am talking about. Where the animation is at @30fps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The timeline will highlight between the start and end frame. There is a [preview range option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#graph-preview-range) that allows a second set of start/end frame values to be used, when this is enabled the one frame range is highlighted in each time based editor. I don't know of any other way to highlight sections of the time based editors.

[image: frame hoghlighting]

The only other option would be using [markers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/markers.html), these are named triangles shown at the bottom of each timeline.

[image: timeline markers]